# NFS: file deletion experiencing delay while "overwriting" not

Tags: linux, nfs, cache, nfs4

I'm having a situation where my file server (linux) is exporting a file system over NFS to a database server (linux). File server (FS) is therefore acting as the NFS server and database server (DBS) is the client. 
The export options on FS are rw,sync and mount options on DBS are rw,sync,acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0,lookupcache=none,vers=4.
I have a process that copies a file to the NFS file system on the FS as . The database uses the contents of this file to its own processing and shortly afterwards the process deletes the file on the FS and copies a second file to the same place using the same file name. Database should then use the second file to do its stuff but for some strange reason on the client side the database still sees the first file. This happens only if I delete the first file before copying the second file. It sometimes takes almost a minute for the client side to show the new file. However, if I "replace" the first file by not deleting it but simply copying the second file and overwriting the first one it shows instantly on the client side.

Would anyone know what is causing this and what I should do to make it work using the "delete-first" method?

Comment: What is the hardware the NFS server is running? Is it hardware RAID? What is the output of `nfsstat -s`?

Comment: try with noac mount option.

Comment: These are virtual servers over Hyper-V.
noac option didn't help here :(
Is there anything in particular I should look for in nfsstat -s? The output is too long to paste here...